# Adding a custom Android build target

Tags: android, sdk, target

I have developed a project with a custom sdk in Eclipse. Now, I need to
build the app using the android tool specified here : http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject

The problem is that when I pass in my project path to the tool as below

android update project --path $directory

I get an error saying the following:

Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android update' command.

My project.properties file is as below

```
#Project target.
target=Custom SDK Addon:19
android.library=true 
android.library.reference.1=../someOtherProject
```

So it seems that the android utility is not recognizing my Custom SDK. I placed the custom SDK into the add-ons folder of the android sdk installation. This works with Eclipse which can find my target but it still does not work for the android utility.

The command "*android list targets*" gives me the following

### Available Android targets:

id: 1 or "android-8"
     Name: Android 2.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 8
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, WQVGA400, WVGA800 (default), WQVGA432, QVGA, WVGA854

---

id: 2 or "android-17"
     Name: Android 4.2.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 17
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA400, WVGA800 (default), WQVGA432, WSVGA, WXGA800, QVGA, WXGA720, WVGA854
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a

As you can see, I can't find my custom target there. How do I make my target visible to the 
android utility?